# How to add other views to UIViewRepresentable?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scenekit

As a beginner in Swift, I wanted to create a painting app where we can choose a photo to frame into a 3d frame.

I'm using SwiftUI and here is my code for the 3d scene.

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct SceneView: UIViewRepresentable {

let scene = SCNScene()

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {

    // create a box
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(createBox())
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(createFrameY(ypos: 30))
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(createFrameY(ypos: -30))
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(createFrameX(xpos: 20))
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(createFrameX(xpos: -20))
    

    // code for creating the camera and setting up lights is omitted for simplicity
    // …

    // retrieve the SCNView
    let scnView = SCNView()
scnView.scene = scene
    return scnView
}

func updateUIView(_ scnView: SCNView, context: Context) {
    scnView.scene = scene

    // allows the user to manipulate the camera
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

    // configure the view
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

    // show statistics such as fps and timing information
    scnView.showsStatistics = true
}

func createBox() -> SCNNode {
    let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 60, length: 40, chamferRadius: 0)
    let box = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeometry)
    box.name = "box"
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true;
    material.isDoubleSided = false
    material.diffuse.contents = "Mona"
    boxGeometry.materials = [material]
    box.localRotate(by: SCNQuaternion(x: 0, y: 0.7071, z: 0, w: 0.7071))
    return box
}

func createFrameY(ypos: Float) -> SCNNode {
    let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 2, height: 2, length: 42, chamferRadius: 0)
    let box = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeometry)
    box.name = "box"
    box.position.y = ypos
    boxGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black
    box.localRotate(by: SCNQuaternion(x: 0, y: 0.7071, z: 0, w: 0.7071))
    return box
}

func createFrameX(xpos: Float) -> SCNNode {
    let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 2, height: 62, length: 2, chamferRadius: 0)
    let box = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeometry)
    box.name = "box"
    box.position.x = xpos
    boxGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black
    return box
}

func removeBox() {
    // check if box exists and remove it from the scene
    guard let box = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "box", recursively: true) else { return }
    box.removeFromParentNode()
}

func addBox() {
    // check if box is already present, no need to add one
    if scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "box", recursively: true) != nil {
        return
    }
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(createBox())
}


}





#if DEBUG
struct ScenekitView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SceneView()
            .previewDevice("iPhone 13 Pro")
    }
}
#endif
```

As I understood, when working with UIViewRepresentable, you cannot have other elements to your screen. So I tried to use this code to have both buttons and the Scene View

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ContentVie: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        Home()
    }
}

struct ContentVie_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentVie()
    }
}

// Home View...

struct Home : View {
    
    @State var models = [
        
        Model(id: 0, name: "Earth", modelName: "Earth.usdz", details: "Earth is the third planet from the Sun and the only astronomical object known to harbor life. According to radiometric dating estimation and other evidence, Earth formed over 4.5 billion years ago. Earth's gravity interacts with other objects in space, especially the Sun and the Moon, which is Earth's only natural satellite. Earth orbits around the Sun in 365.256 solar days.")
    ]

    @State var index = 0

    var scene = SCNScene(named: "Earth.usdz")
    
    var body: some View{
        
        VStack{
            
            // Going to use SceneKit Scene View....
            
            // default is first object ie: Earth...
            
            // Scene View Has a default Camera View...
            // if you nedd custom means add there...
            
            SceneView(scene: scene, options: [.autoenablesDefaultLighting,.allowsCameraControl])
            // for user action...
            // setting custom frame...
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width , height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2)
            
            ZStack{
                
                // Forward and backward buttons...
                
                HStack{
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        withAnimation{
                            
                            if index > 0{
                                
                                index -= 1
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }, label: {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                            .font(.system(size: 35, weight: .bold))
                            .opacity(index == 0 ? 0.3 : 1)
                    })
                    .disabled(index == 0 ? true : false)
                    
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        withAnimation{
                            
                            if index < models.count{
                                
                                index += 1
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }, label: {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                            .font(.system(size: 35, weight: .bold))
                        // disabling button when no other data ....
                            .opacity(index == models.count - 1 ? 0.3 : 1)
                    })
                    .disabled(index == models.count - 1 ? true : false)
                }
                
                Text(models[index].name)
                    .font(.system(size: 45, weight: .bold))
            }
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.vertical,30)
            
            // Details....
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15, content: {
                
                Text("About")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                
                Text(models[index].details)
            })
            .padding(.horizontal)
            
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
        }
    }
}

// Data Model...

struct Model : Identifiable {
    
    var id : Int
    var name : String
    var modelName : String
    var details : String
}
```

But I cannot add SCNNodes to the scene. Do you know how I could combine both to make it work?

Comment: I'm confused what the problem is, can you create a [mre]? When you say `"I cannot add SCNNodes to the scene"` do you mean you don't know how, they aren't visible, etc? A bit more detail would help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.